# How do I configure cypress-sql-server with no cypress.json?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to setup cypress-sql-server, but I'm using version 10.8.0, which does not use cypress.json to configure the environment.  All of the setup instructions I've found refer to using cypress.json to configure the plug-in. I am running into an error:

```
tasksqlServer:execute, SELECT 'Bob'
CypressError
cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error:

The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method. You must register it before using cy.task()

Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here:
D:\git\mcare.automation\client\cypress\cypress.config.jsLearn more
node_modules/cypress-sql-server/src/commands/db.js:7:1
   5 |     }
   6 | 
>  7 |     cy.task('sqlServer:execute', query).then(response => {
     | ^
   8 |       let result = [];
   9 |
```

cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const sqlServer = require("cypress-sql-server");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // allows db data to be accessed in tests
      config.db = {
        "userName": "user",
        "password": "pass",
        "server": "myserver",
        "options": {
          "database": "mydb",
          "encrypt": true,
          "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
        }
      }

      // code from /plugins/index.js
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
      on('task', tasks);

      return config      
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

testSQL.spec.js

```
describe('Testing SQL queries', () => {
    
    it("It should return Bob", () => {
        cy.sqlServer("SELECT 'Bob'").should('eq', 'Bob');
        
});
})
```

My versions:

```js
\cypress> npx cypress --version
Cypress package version: 10.8.0
Cypress binary version: 10.8.0
Electron version: 19.0.8
Bundled Node version:
16.14.2
``
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the install instruction currently given by `cypress-sql-server` for **Cypress v9**

> **Plugin file**
>
> The plug-in can be initialised in your cypress/plugins/index.js file as below.
>
> ```js
> const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
>
> module.exports = (on, config) => {
>   tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
>   on('task', tasks);
> }
> ```

Translating that into **Cypress v10+**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      // allows db data to be accessed in tests
      config.db = {
        "userName": "user",
        "password": "pass",
        "server": "myserver",
        "options": {
          "database": "mydb",
          "encrypt": true,
          "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
        }
      }

      // code from /plugins/index.js
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
      on('task', tasks);

      return config
    },
  },
})
```

Other variations work, such as putting the `"db": {...}` section below the `"e2e: {...}"` section, but ***not*** in the `"env": {...}` section.

#### Custom commands

Instructions for **Cypress v9**

> **Commands file**
>
> The extension provides multiple sets of commands. You can import the ones you need.
> Example `support/index.js` file.
>
> ```js
> import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
> sqlServer.loadDBCommands();
> ```

For **Cypress v10+**

Just move this code to `support/e2e.js`

Comment: I'm still running into errors:
cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error:

The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method. You must register it before using cy.task()

Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here:
D:\git\mcare.automation\client\cypress\cypress.config.js

Comment: I did a straight copy/paste of what you gave me.  the on('task', tasks) line is there.

Comment: Looks like the `cypress.config.js` code is failing silently - there should be a `const` in front of `tasks` - see change above.

Comment: I'm still running into the same error. I've updated the original post with my current code. Thank you for all of you help so far, btw. I know I'm a lot closer than I was.

Comment: I get `Failed to connect to myserver:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myserver` - running without Sql Server installed and your dummy connection info as above.  So the task is registered and attempting to connect. If there's no obvious typos, is `cypress.config.js` in the right place?

Comment: #$%$%^##$!!!!!!! Thank you. For some reason, I had two copies of the file and I was updating the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

**For cypress 10+ in config file:**

```
    const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

    //process.env.server with npm i dotenv can be used for sensitive data in loadDBPlugin properties

    const yourDatabaseName = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin({
      server: "",
      port: ,
      userName: "",
      password: "",
      options: {
        database: "",
        encrypt: true,
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
      }
    })
    
    on("task", {
          'sqlServer:execute': (sql) => yourDatabaseName['sqlServer:execute'](sql)
         })
```

**in support/e2e.js file :**

```
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server'
sqlServer.loadDBCommands()
```

**in test:**

```
cy.sqlServer(`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=''
      ).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
```

Answer (score -1):

`cypress.json` is a way to specify [Cypress environment variables.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting) Instead of using a `cypress.json` file, you can use any of the strategies in that link.

If you just wanted to include them in your `cypress.config.js`, it would look something like this:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    env: {
      db: {
        // your db values here
      }
    }
  }
})
```