# Trouble connecting to SQL Server with Cypress

Tags: sql-server, cypress

Having an issue with where i seem to be connecting to SQL Server but cannot find the server/db.

[image]

I have been trying to follow the steps in this guide for Cypress 9 but to no avail.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server

There was an answer on SO that i've been trying to use but I can't reply to a comment and add a comment but it was deleted by the mods for some reason. This is the URL to the answer I have been trying to follow but can't connect.

[How to configure cypress-sql-server with no cypress.json? (updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831176/how-to-configure-cypress-sql-server-with-no-cypress-json-updated)

Has someone please got a working example?

cypress.config.ts

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const sqlServer = require("cypress-sql-server");

module.exports = defineConfig({  
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // allows db data to be accessed in tests
      config.db = {
        "userName": "x",
        "password": "x",
        "server": "xxx\\SQLEXPRESS",
        "options": {
          "database": "xxxxxx",
          "encrypt": true,
          "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
          "trusted_connection": true
        }
      }

      // code from /plugins/index.js
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
      on('task', tasks);

      return config      
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});

export default defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
  screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
  fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
  video: false,
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'cypress/reports',
    charts: true,
    reportPageTitle: 'xxxxxxxx',
    embeddedScreenshots: true,
    inlineAssets: true,
  },  
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.ts')(on, config)
    },
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/tests/orders/*',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
})
```

index.ts

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
  require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);  
  return config;
}
```

e2e.ts

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
import './commands';
import 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter/register';
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
sqlServer.loadDBCommands(); 
}
```

Tried creating a new sysadmin also on SQL Server in case it was an access issue

Comment: A port number will override the named instance resolution.  And the error appears to be trying to connect on port 1433, which SQL Server Express does not listen on by default.  Try to use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable TCP/IP for the instance and configure it to listen on port 1433.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. I'll have a go at it. On my SSMS I checked the properties earlier and it states port is 1433 however when I checked SQL Server Configuration Manager TCP/IP was disabled. When I enabled and restarted, under All IP it was showing port as 0. Can I configure port 1433 from that screen yeah?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP/IP Properties for your instance should look like this to make it listen on port 1433:  On IPALL clear the TCP Dynamic Ports and set TCP Port to 1433.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I have done this just before you commented and still not finding it. I have checked that the port is enabled also for 1433 via an SSMS query. Should I try a different port?

Comment: I got it working by changing the server to 127.0.0.1 - Not sure why it wasn't playing ball with the actual server name! Thanks for the help in regards to enabling the port. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You have the pattern for `cypress.config.js` plus the one for `cypress.config.ts` in your config file, but it's either/or not both at once.
See example [Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#component).

Since you use typescript, try

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server'

const dbSettings = {
  "userName": "x",
  "password": "x",
  "server": "xxx\\SQLEXPRESS",
  "options": {
    "database": "xxxxxx",
    "encrypt": true,
    "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
    "trusted_connection": true
  }
}

export default defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  ...  // other cofinfig settings
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.db = dbSettings;
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbSettings);
      on('task', tasks);
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.ts')(on, config)
    },
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/tests/orders/*',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks Fody. I got it working in the end up but your answer is cleaner. I'll tidy it up tomorrow. Appreciate the comment