# Cypress 12.5.1 cypress-sql-server typescript configuration

Tags: typescript, installation, configuration, cypress

I am trying to setup cypress-sql-server for use on this environment. I have configured cypress for typescript and have followed the instructions at [how-to-configure-cypress-sql-server-with-no-cypress-json-updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831176/how-to-configure-cypress-sql-server-with-no-cypress-json-updated) and then updated that code based on [trouble connecting to sql server with cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74197951/trouble-connecting-to-sql-server-with-cypress) but I am seeing an error indicating that Property 'db' does not exist on type 'PluginConfigOptions'.ts(2339)

Here is the code section from my  cypress.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server'
// verify download import
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');
const dbSettings = {
  "userName": "x",
  "password": "x",
  "server": "xxx\\SQLEXPRESS",
  "options": {
    "database": "xxxxxx",
    "encrypt": true,
    "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
    "trusted_connection": true
  }
}

export default defineConfig({
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    charts: true,
    reportPageTitle: 'My Report Name',
    embeddedScreenshots: true,
    inlineAssets: true,
    saveAllAttempts: false,
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // allows db data to be accessed in tests
      config.db = dbSettings;
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbSettings);

      // code from /plugins/index.js
      on('task', tasks);
      
      // implement node event listeners here
      require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);  
      //------------------------------------  
      // verify download import
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks); 
      //------------------------------------ 
      
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.ts')(on, config)
      
    },
    
    env:{
      QASupportApi: "https://myurl",
      //snapshotOnly: true,
      requestMode: true,      
      hideCredentials:true,
      "hosts":{
        
      },
    }
  },
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  viewportHeight: 1000,
  viewportWidth: 1400,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 0,
  "screenshotsFolder": "TestReport/assets",
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 2,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 1
  }
});
```

I am unsure of how to resolve this issue as it does not seem to have been a problem for anyone in the article.

[intellisense error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KALWH.png)

I have tried viewing the definition for config and PluginConfigOptions but not having any luck.

e2e.ts

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example support/e2e.ts is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands';
import './exceptions';
import 'cypress-real-events/support';
import 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter/register';
import 'cypress-plugin-api';
import "cypress-ntlm-auth/dist/commands";
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
sqlServer.loadDBCommands(); 



// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')
```

cypress\plugins\index.ts

```
const TestRailReporter = require('cypress-testrail');
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
  require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);  
  require(TestRailReporter(on, config);
  return config;
}
```

from e2e.ts I am seeing this message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i54W.png)

and when trying

```
npm i --save-dev @types/cypress-sql-server
```

I get this error in terminal

```
PS C:\repo\Cy-Starter> npm i --save-dev @types/cypress-sql-server
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fcypress-sql-server - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/cypress-sql-server@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-18T21_49_48_784Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\repo\Cy-Starter> npm i --save-dev @types/cypress-sql-server
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fcypress-sql-server - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/cypress-sql-server@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-18T21_52_19_696Z-debug-0.log
```

not sure what to do with this alternative solution `if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing` declare module 'cypress-sql-server';`

Comment: OK so I figured this out and will post the working version shortly.

Comment: Did you find the solution please post your working version. I am also facing the same problem @David Grandfield

Answer (score 0):

I have this working now using "cypress-sql-server" and cypress version ^12.5.1.

Here is the working cypress.config.ts file.  You will need to update with your connection information:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
// verify download import
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const dbSettings = {
    userName:"yourusername",
    password:"yourpassword",
    server: "yourservername",
    domain: "yourdomain",
    options: {
      database: "yourdatabasename",
      encrypt: true,
      rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
      trusted_connection: true,
      multipleActiveResultSets: true,
      trustServerCertificate: true
    }
}

export default defineConfig({
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    charts: true,
    reportPageTitle: 'Test Report',
    embeddedScreenshots: true,
    inlineAssets: true,
    saveAllAttempts: false,
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // allows db data to be accessed in tests
      const tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbSettings);
      on('task', tasks);      

      // implement node event listeners here
      require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin')(on);  
      //------------------------------------  
      // verify download import
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks); 
      //------------------------------------ 
      return config;
            
    },
    
    env:{
      QASupportApi: "https://qasupport.com",
      //snapshotOnly: true,
      requestMode: true,      
      hideCredentials:true,
      
    }
  },
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  viewportHeight: 1000,
  viewportWidth: 1400,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 50,
  "screenshotsFolder": "TestReport/assets",
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 0,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 0
  }
});
```

and here is the e2e.ts

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example support/e2e.ts is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands';
import './exceptions';
import 'cypress-real-events/support';
import 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter/register';
import 'cypress-plugin-api';
import "cypress-ntlm-auth/dist/commands";
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
sqlServer.loadDBCommands(); 




// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')
```

and a sample usage from a generic database

```
describe('admin account schema tests', () => {
        
    it('can call a database and execute a query', () => {
            cy.sqlServer("SELECT TOP(10) FirstName,LastName,UserIdentifier FROM core.Users").then((users) =>{
                cy.log(users);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am working to see if there is a way to make the connection dynamic.  The root problem is that the connection is established as part of the preprocessing and so Cypress.env is not available nor is cy.fixture so making the connection generic is proving to be problematic.  For now I would have to create a test project per environment which is sub-optimal.